# Using celery directly in cmd gives right result, but nssm wrapped celery service won't do the same, why?

Tags: python, celery, nssm

It's a celery worker doing some tasks in graphics on Windows.

Task is correctly done when I manually run `celery worker -A ...` in cmd.

But if I use nssm to wrap the celery command as a service, the task will return a wrong result (it still can go to the end and give a result, but its wrong).

I have checked the log, the only difference is it will throw an error (or warning?) like this: `Failed to created the Direct3D device`. I can't figure out what it means.

Anyone can give me some idea?